# It is recommended to install UTF-8 locale, otherwise all CLI calls which use escapeshellarg() will strip multibyte

Tags: pimcore

I am installing Pimcore/demo application on MacOS+Brew+Php@8.2 and received the **error**:

> [ERROR] The following prerequisites failed It is recommended to
> install UTF-8 locale, otherwise all CLI calls which use
> escapeshellarg() will strip multibyte characters (see
> https://packages.debian.org/en/stable/locales-all)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solved it:

```
brew install icu4c
brew link --force icu4c
```

Edit file:

```
subl ~/.zshrc
```

and added:

> export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
>
> export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

**Current State**:

After this for command:

```
locale
```

I have the following output:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Installation is successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for linux Debian Ubuntu etc, including emulation on Windows:

**Diagnostics:**

See your current state using command

```
locale
```

probably you have empty `LC_ALL` something like:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Solution:**

You need to set LC_ALL to have the same value that LC_COLLATE has. e.g.:

```
export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Perhaps you will need to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install locales-all
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales      # enable 'all', then 'ok'
```

**Result:**

After this your would be defined. Something like:

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

or following if you are simulating Linux on a Windows computer:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```